# Umbraco surface controller inside v6 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have implemented a Surface controller in my Umbraco application (v6) however, it doesn't work.

Here's the simple Hello World class:

```
public class MySurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Content("hello world");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately whenever I access it, I get an HTTP 404 error.  I have attempted the following URLs:

- /Umbraco/surface/my
- /Umbraco/surface/mysurface
- /Umbraco/surface/mysurfacecontroller
- /Umbraco/surface/my/index
- /Umbraco/surface/mysurface/index
- /Umbraco/surface/mysurfacecontroller/index

My Global.asax inherits from Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things here:

You no longer need to end the name of you controller "SurfaceController", just inherit from `SurfaceController`.

Also you wouldn't need the path prefix `/Umbraco/surface/`, you should be able to access the Index() action just at `/my/`, if your controller was called  the `MyController`.

**Edit:**

Assuming that you want to serve pages from your controller, you will need to amend the web.config AppSetting entry to include your controller's path

```
<add key="umbracoReservedPaths" value="~/umbraco,~/install/,~/my" />
```

You will also need to register a route specifically for your controller from the global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "my/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It's important that this is specific to your controller as you do not want it to override any Umbraco routing.

Comment: OK, I have changed the name of the controller to MyController and attempted to access it at /my/index, /mycontroller/index, /my/, /umbraco/surface/my, /Umbraco/surface/my/index.  Nothing but an error 404.

Comment: I've updated the answer, you may not have made/know about the additional changes.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  However, I have found another component which is clearing out the RouteTable.  I was previously unable to debug because VS was giving an error whenever I start debugging!  Anyway, I have now solved this cascade of issues!  thanks

Comment: Where do you map this route? Because umbraco's `global.asax` uses their own `UmbracoApplication` class. I tried creating an `MvcApplication` class by inheriting from Umbraco's `UmbracoApplication` class and map route in `onApplicationStarting` event but that results in error - "The matched route does not include a 'controller' route value, which is required."

Comment: You should map the route in OnApplicationStarted in your Global.asax class inheriting UmbracoApplication.